# How to prevent Xcode from disabling idle timer?

Tags: ios, xcode

When you run an app with Xcode on attached device it's screen never dims or turns off. This might be handy in some situations, but it goes so far that the screen might be on with the same content for an hours, even after the Mac with Xcode goes to sleep. That might lead to ghosting and potential screen deterioration.

How to prevent Xcode from disabling idle timer?

Comment: I'm not sure you can. Just put the iOS device to sleep before walking away or ending the debugging session.

Comment: @rmaddy I always forget to do this :-)